# All but the last N elements of iterator in Python

Tags: python, iterator

What is the best way to get all but the last N elements of an iterator in Python?  Here is an example of it in theoretical action:

```
>>> list(all_but_the_last_n(range(10), 0))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> list(all_but_the_last_n(range(10), 2))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Comment: You should use `collections.deque` as Ignacio recommends.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for the fun of it, here's a variation on Ignacio's solution that doesn't require a deque.

```
>>> def truncate(it, n):
...     cache = [next(it) for i in range(n)]
...     index = 0
...     for val in it:
...         val, cache[index] = cache[index], val
...         index = (index + 1) % n
...         yield val
```

I wasn't especially concerned with speed when I wrote the above... but perhaps this would be a tad faster:

```
def truncate(it, n):
    cache = [next(it) for i in range(n)]
    index = 0
    for val in it:
        yield cache[index]
        cache[index] = val
        index = (index + 1) % n
```

Comment: Nice use of a circular buffer.  This is probably the fastest solution.

Comment: @Neil, thanks. Not sure why I decided to use `while True` in retrospect... there, fixed.

Comment: if we add it = iter(it) as the first line of the function, it will support non-iterators

Comment: i timed my deque version and this circular buffer version which i had to modify adding `it=iter(it)` changing `next(it)` to `it.next()` (with python 2.5.2) . i found that for `list(f(l,50))` with `l=list(range(10000))` where `f` is one of the two functions, the deque version took `5.98 msec` while this circular buffer version took `6.48 msec`. `list(l)` takes `340 usec`.

Comment: @Dan D., interesting -- perhaps my new version is faster? (I timed it on my machine and it was faster than my previous version, but I didn't test it against yours.)

Comment: @Dan, @senderle: I bet the `deque` is implemented in C.  If someone had written this circular buffer in C as well, I think it would win.

Answer (score 6):

Use a [`collections.deque`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.deque). Push `N` items from the source on the first invocation. On each subsequent invocation, pop an item out, push an item in from the source, and yield the popped item.

Comment: @Fraklin: Please feel free to double-check it.

Comment: +1: You might want to point out in case it's not obvious that this solution is O(N) memory instead of O(M) where M is the length of the sequence.

Comment: this is what I was looking for.  Though I don't see a clean way to use a deque here.  Using a list instead allow for len(fifo), but adds unnecessary overhear ...

Comment: You can take the length of a `deque` as well, it just isn't O(1).

Comment: Still don't think that's the answer. If you yield poped items, it'll return those from the end.

Comment: @zdwiel: you don't need to do `len(fifo)`, just start with a loop: `for i, _ in izip(iterable, range(n)): fifo.append(i)`.

Comment: @Neil G: that doesn't work if you pass a list into iterable.  Iterable include generators as well as list and range(N).

Comment: Who on earth downvoted this? If you interpret this sensibly, it's 100% correct.

Comment: @senderle: It's the person that thinks that All Solutions Must Include Code. I have no clue why they're like that, and I can't help them recover from it.

Comment: @Ignacio: I agree.  I thought it was even better how zdwiel was able to take your idea and write the code himself.

Comment: fyi, I didn't down vote this answer.  However, part of the reason I come here is for these kinds of functions which aren't in standard libraries, yet are complex and general enough that its nice to use code that has already been speed tested and community checked for bugs.

Answer (score 4):

Based on Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams's description:

```
from collections import deque

def all_but_the_last_n(iterable, count):
    q = deque()
    i = iter(iterable)
    for n in range(count):
        q.append(i.next())
    for item in i:
        q.append(item)
        yield q.popleft()
```

I wondered whether it was better to use the deque right to left (append, popleft) or left to right  (appendleft, pop). So i timed it with python 2.5.2 and found that rtl was `3.59 usec` while ltr was `3.53 usec`. The difference of `0.06 usec` is not significant. the test was to append a single item and pop a single item.

Answer (score 1):

Using Ignacio's solution.

```
import collections
def all_but_the_last_n(iterable, n):
    it = iter(iterable)
    fifo = collections.deque()
    for _, i in zip(range(n), it):
        fifo.append(i)
    for i in it:
        fifo.append(i)
        yield fifo.popleft()

print(list(all_but_the_last_n(range(10), 3)))
print(list(all_but_the_last_n('abcdefghijkl', 3)))
```

It is unfortunate that `collections` does not have a circular buffer.  This would be more efficient from a cache miss standpoint with one.

Comment: ah iter(iterable) was what I was missing.  Thanks!

Comment: actually, this is incorrect ... list(all_but_the_last_n(range(10), 3)) -> [0, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6] instead of [0, 1, 2, **3**, 4, 5, 6]

Answer (score 1):

For a list you could do this:

```
def all_but_the_last_n(aList, N):
    return aList[:len(aList) - N]

myList = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
N = 4

print(all_but_the_last_n(myList, N))
```

Will print:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is compact (aside from `consume` recipe taken from `itertools` recipes) and should run at C speed:

```
import collections
import operator
from itertools import islice, tee


def truncate(iterable, n):
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    consume(b, n)
    return map(operator.itemgetter(0), zip(a, b))


# From itertools recipes
def consume(iterator, n=None):
    "Advance the iterator n-steps ahead. If n is None, consume entirely."
    # Use functions that consume iterators at C speed.
    if n is None:
        # feed the entire iterator into a zero-length deque
        collections.deque(iterator, maxlen=0)
    else:
        # advance to the empty slice starting at position n
        next(islice(iterator, n, n), None)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work:

list[:-N]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).